# CSS Positioning an icon at the top right side of the image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a `close` icon from bootstraps sprite, in the top right side of the image ( not the box). I took this from a working example, but it wont work for me. It always ends up outside the box and at the right corner of the screen.

How can I get this right? I've setup a fiddle, but could not figure how to get the sprite in there. Can you help?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eugbrqwc/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Delete Image Icon Dev</title>

<style>

img.thumbnail {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}

.image:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.delete {
    position:absolute;
     top:0;
    right:0;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="image"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/dsPfaSjs.jpg"><i class="icon-remove blue delete"></i></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is thumbnail size always going to be the same? (90X90)

Comment: The thumbnails width will always be 150px. The height can be anything.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the actual `<img>` size?

Comment: @misterManSam The thumbnail will always be 150px wide (it's cut down to that size). The height isn't fixed.

Comment: With [something like this](http://jsbin.com/fecuho/1/edit) it can be any height. Anything that can be changed with that example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example can take an image of any height.

1. Turn the `<i class="delete">` into a `<div>`
2. Wrap the `<img>` with the new delete div
3. Give `.image:before` a `min-height: 150px;` and *remove* the fixed height on `.image`
4. Apply `position: relative` to `.delete`
5. Apply the delete button to a pseudo elment with `.delete:after` or place another `<i>` to make it interactive.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/zaxopi/1/edit)

[Example without the delete pseudo element](http://jsbin.com/sazug/1/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="image"> 
    <div class="icon-remove blue delete">       
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/dsPfaSjs.jpg">
        <!-- <i class="delete-button"></i> if you need to use a real element -->
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 150px;
}

.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.delete {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.delete:after {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
     top:0;
    right:0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #F00;
}

/* If you need to use a real element remove .delete:after and use this  -- 
.delete .delete-button {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
     top:0;
    right:0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #F00;
}*/
```

Comment: I really don't understand why even when I have everything copied from your example, I end up with such odd results on my local machine...

Comment: Ok. Got it working. Now, how do I get my `<i class="icon-remove blue"></i>` in there where your red square is?

Comment: It looks like you should use the second example in my answer - `Example without the delete pseudo element` and place the classes on that `<i>` :)

Comment: @misteManSam Thanks. The second one works really well. A little tweaking needed, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

/e

you need to update your markup:

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="img">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/dsPfaSjs.jpg" />
    <i class="icon-remove blue delete"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

and also your css:

```
img.thumbnail {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
.image:before {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.image .img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    position: relative;
}
.delete {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eugbrqwc/17/**

you don't need the height, width and background in .delete - just for showing purposes

Comment: I think he wants "in the top right side of the image (not the box)".

Comment: That's right at the top right corner of the box. I'm trying to get it at the top right corner of the image.

Comment: Almost, but adding `position:relative` to the image itself breaks up the vertical align of the image

Comment: why do you need position:relative on the image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `position:relative;` to the `.image` div and then set the `top` and `right` parameters to the `.delete` element.

```
.image {
    /* Other rules here */
    position:relative;
}

.delete {
    /* Other rules here */
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:15px;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle also: http://jsfiddle.net/eugbrqwc/15/. I added some text to the `.delete` element just to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper `<div>` around your image and icon, set it to `display: inline-block` and `position: relative`. Its size will conform to the image's, while allowing the icon to absolutely position itself to the top right.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I created a fork of your fiddle and I have solved it. http://jsfiddle.net/bkx1dnsb/1/

You needed `Position:relative on the image class`

There was no icon so i added an X but your icon will be in the same spot.

Use the top & right from the delete class to tinker the positioning.

The reason it was going to the top right was because position absolute is relative to the browser window. Unless you set position releative on the parent of the absolute positioned element.

Hope that helps